# Iterm2 window resizing through commands not working

Tags: iterm2

printf '\e[8;50;200t' which sets the width and height of the window to 50 and 200 respectively does not seem to work on Iterm2 Version 3. 
It works perfectly fine on the native terminal.

Answer (score 4):

`Iterm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Terminal > Disable session-initiated window resizing > (uncheck)`

Thanks to https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/1818